# How to create custom intrinsic elements in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to know how to create custom intrinsic elements in React (such as  in react three fiber).
Suppose i have a simple component

```
const Book = () => <div>book!</div>
```

And i want to use this just like web-components,

```
<book />
```

That is: 1) lowercase component, 2) doesnt need to be imported as react renderer recognizes it and maps to Book func component

I did my research and it seems R3F uses `reconciler` lib of react to tinker with the default react renderer but r3f's source code is too complex.

Does anyone have any articles/tutorials or example of how i can create such intrinsic components in react?

I tried to check how it's done in R3F but the source code is too complex as it hugely references webgl and three js

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible with react. If you want a web component, why not use the web component spec?

Comment: Spencer, React three fiber implemented it with <mesh /> for example, they do something with reconciler so the react's renderer recognizes it (afaik)

Comment: What's the use case, out of curiosity? Why doesn't a normal component work in your case?